# How do I setup GitLab CI/CD for a tor hidden service, using Docker images?

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, tor

I have been trying to do it, already. Although, some errors appeared and I don't know what else to do.

I think the problem here is that `rsync` is trying to connect to the host using port 22, when it should be **9150**.

The only job that ever fails is `deploy:tor`. Compilation is fine.

This is the error output:

```
1615506885 PERROR torsocks[15]: socks5 libc connect: Connection refused (in socks5_connect() at socks5.c:202)
ssh: connect to host [MASKED] port 22: Connection refused
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(228) [sender=v3.13.0_rc2-264-g725ac7fb]
```

`torrc`:

```
## The directory for keeping all the keys/etc
DataDirectory /var/lib/tor

## Tor opens a socks proxy on port 9150
SocksPort 0.0.0.0:9150
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.13

RUN apk update \
 && apk upgrade \
 && apk add --no-cache \
            tor --update-cache --repository http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/ --allow-untrusted \
            bash \
            torsocks \
            rsync \
            openssh-client \
            sshpass \
            ca-certificates \
 && update-ca-certificates \
 && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

EXPOSE 9150

ADD ./torrc /etc/tor/torrc
RUN chown -R tor /etc/tor

USER tor

CMD /usr/bin/tor -f /etc/tor/torrc
```

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
variables:
  JEKYLL_ENV: production
  LC_ALL: C.UTF-8

stages:
  - compile
  - deploy

compile:pages:
  image: ruby
  stage: compile
  before_script:
    - gem install bundler
    - bundle install
  script:
  - bundle exec jekyll build -d public
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  cache:
    paths:
      - public/
  only:
  - master

deploy:tor:
  image: riservatoxyz/pages-hidden-service
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
  - echo "starting hidden service deploy job!"
  script:
  - torsocks rsync -zv --progress --rsh="/usr/bin/sshpass -p $TOR_SSH_PASSWORD ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l $TOR_SSH_USERNAME" public/_site/* $TOR_SSH_HOST:www
  - echo "build sent to hidden service!"
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

### Other Details

- I am using `sshpass` because I am unable to setup ssh passwordless login, on my hidden service host.

  - It's not a big deal, though. Since I'm using secret and masked variables.